# jQuery fancybox ajax function issue with firefox and chrome browser

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I have jQuery Fancybox 2 plugin from fancybox.net and I created a multiple links loop id records from database using fancybox.ajax as class look like this...

```
<a class="ajaxbox" href="showproduct.php?id=1" title="Show Product">Show Product ID 1</a>
<a class="ajaxbox" href="showproduct.php?id=2" title="Show Product">Show Product ID 2</a>
<a class="ajaxbox" href="showproduct.php?id=3" title="Show Product">Show Product ID 3</a>
```

and my javascript code...

```
$(function(){
    $(".ajaxbox").fancybox({
        maxWidth : 900,
        maxHeight : 700,
        fitToView : false,
        autoSize     : true,
        openEffect : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        type : 'ajax'
    });
});
```

In IE and Safari it works great without any problems but I got a problem in Chrome and Firefox (14.0.1) The problem is when I click X button the fancybox is closed but when I open same fancybox.ajax again the backgroud opacity get darker and I try to close fancybox again the content is closed but the background is still dark. I have to click on the dark background again to close opacity effect. So, I try to open same fancybox.ajax same link again third time and I got background more darker than second time.

Btw. others fancybox function is ok only problem with ajax function.

Comment: It seems like your ajax function somehow changes the opacity settings of the overlay mask, but it's a guess. It could be easier if you share a link.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make a sample links

Comment: Well it's weird (-_-) I just make a sample page with above example code but it works great without any problem but for the real site it doesn't.

Comment: why you don't load your css file from the real site to the sample page? it will help to track the issue down.

Comment: @JFK I added my explanation above. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I found what happen with fancybox.ajax function.
>
> First problem, I created file name `javascript.js` and added it into all pages (Included `firstpage.php` and `showproduct.php` like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

> and I added the fancybox script into `javascript.js`
>
> I think fancybox is **confused** with `javascript.js` So, I try to remove `.ajaxbox` from `javascript.js` and move the script to `firstpage.php` look like this.

**firstpage.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".ajaxbox").fancybox({
        maxWidth : 900,
        maxHeight : 700,
        fitToView : false,
        autoSize     : true,
        openEffect : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        type : 'ajax'
    });
});
</script>
```

> and **showproduct.php** (without `.ajaxbox` function)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

> and test it again... Ok. Everything back to normal.
>
> But! I need the same javascript function works with all pages. So, I created a new function look like this and added it back into `javascript.js`

```
function openajaxfancybox(url) {
    $.fancybox({
        maxWidth : 900,
        maxHeight : 700,
        fitToView : false,
        autoSize     : true,
        openEffect   : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        type : 'ajax',
        href : url
    });
}
```

> and replaced onclick with href look like this ...

```
<a onclick="openajaxfancybox('showproduct.php?id=1');">Show Product ID 1</a>
<a onclick="openajaxfancybox('showproduct.php?id=2');">Show Product ID 2</a>
<a onclick="openajaxfancybox('showproduct.php?id=3');">Show Product ID 3</a>
```

> Test it again and now! everything works perfectly as I want without any problems. :)
>
> PS: Tested on IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari